# adb returns "error: unknown host service"

Tags: android, bash, adb

Below is code I've written that is supposed to take a list of all devices connected, extract their serial numbers, and than spit them out to the terminal. When I run this script I get `error: unknown host service` which spawns out of my `Return Serial` function

```
ReturnSerial () {
    adb -s $usb shell getprop | grep ro.serial | awk '{print $2}'
}

for usb in $(adb devices -l | awk '/ device usb:/{print $2}'); do ReturnSerial ; done
```

I don't understand what this error means. I have many other functions that I run in the same fashion that do not get caught.

Also worth noting, the devices I work with do not spit out their serial number on a simple `adb devices` command, thus why I need to use their `usb` locator and extract the serial number from their properties.

Comment: `awk '/ device usb:/{print $2}')` prints `device`

Comment: @AlexP. That was it. I'll close the question, thanks

Comment: on an unrelated note, why grepping for `ro.serial`? just do `getprop ro.serial`. usually it's `ro.serialno` though

Comment: @AlexP. Purely aescetic. A list of `[SERIALNO]` look better than just `SERIALNO` personally.